# Is there an R function to create a variable for when multiple logical vectors are true?

Tags: r

For my dataset each person is identified by a unique number. I have four logical vectors denoting when a person has a particular disease. These are not mutually exclusive, i.e. people can have multiple diseases at once. I want to create an additional logical vector which indicates when someone has multiple diseases of any kind, so that the output for the below would be a fifth variable of FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
logical_1 <- c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE) 
logical_2 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)
logical_3 <- c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)
logical_4 <- c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE)

dataframe <- data.frame(x, logical_1, logical_2, logical_3, logical_4)
```

I'm not sure what function would be best to do this, so any basic pointers would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `rowSums` on the logical columns to count the number of TRUEs in each row, then see which rows have more than 1 TRUE value:

```
dataframe$result = rowSums(dataframe[2:5]) > 1
dataframe
#   x logical_1 logical_2 logical_3 logical_4 result
# 1 1     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      TRUE  FALSE
# 2 2      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE  FALSE
# 3 3     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE  FALSE
# 4 4      TRUE      TRUE     FALSE     FALSE   TRUE
```

Comment: Thank you! How would I select rows by their names rather than by their row numbers?

Comment: I don't know what you mean --- your example doesn't have row names, and we didn't use row names or row numbers, nor did we "select" anything. Maybe you should ask a new question.

Comment: But generally you can use row names just like row numbers in `[`. `mtcars["Valiant", ]` gives the row of `mtcars` that has row name "Valiant".

Comment: Or do you mean **column** names? like where I have `dataframe[2:5]`? You can use column names just the same `rowSums(dataframe[c("logical_1", "logical_2", "logical_3", "logical_4")]) > 1`. Or if you use `dplyr` you can get fancy with the select helpers...

Comment: Sorry. I mean columns. I'm assuming 2:5 refers to columns 2 to 5. My dataset is very large so it makes sense to refer to columns by their names.

Comment: Yeah, you can use a vector of column names and a vector of column numbers interchangeably in this answer.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you.